# Complex Fourier Series coefficient reduction.

Tags: fourier-series

I am trying to understand the Complex Fourier series solution for the following function, as printed on "Fundamentals of Electric Circuits" by Alexander & Sadiku:

[image]

The solution printed on the solutions manual is:

[image]

Please note the highlighted functions inside the red squares.

Take for example the identity inside the first red square (the one on the left). I was under the impression that $e^{jn\pi/2}$ was equal to $jsin(n\pi/2)$ only when 'n' is odd, meaning that:

\begin{array}{l l}
    cos(n\pi/2) & \quad \text{if $n$ is even}\\
    jsin(n\pi/2) & \quad \text{if $n$ is odd}
  \end{array}

Or in other words:
\begin{array}{l l}
    (-1)^{n/2} & \quad \text{if $n$ is even}\\
    j(-1)^{(n-1)/2} & \quad \text{if $n$ is odd}
  \end{array}

***Is any scenario possible in which the identities inside the red squares are true for any n, regardless if n is odd or even?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eulers' identity is
$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$$
Where I use $i$ for the imaginary unit and $x\in\mathbb R$. This gives
$$e^{\pm i \pi \frac n2} = \cos ( \pm \pi \frac n2 ) + i \sin (\pm \pi \frac n2) = \cos(\pi \frac n2) \pm i \sin (\pi \frac n2)$$
By axial symmetry of $\cos$ and point symmetry of $\sin$. Your "thought" isn't quite correct,
$$e^{i\pi \frac n2} = (e^{i\frac \pi 2})^n = i^n = \cases{i & $n\equiv 1 \mod 4$ \\
-1 & $n\equiv 2 \mod 4$ \\
-i & $n\equiv 3 \mod 4$ \\
1 & $n\equiv 0 \mod 4$}$$
This means your values are correct for the expression $e^{i\pi \frac n4}$

Comment: Agreed, following that reasoning is correct, however it seems odd to me that if if instead of factoring the n, you apply directly Eulers identity, it yields $e^{\pm i \pi \frac n2} = \cos ( \pm \pi \frac n2 ) + i \sin (\pm \pi \frac n2) = \cos(\pi \frac n2) \pm i \sin (\pi \frac n2)$ and in that case, $cos ( \pm \pi \frac n2 ) = (-1)^{n/2}$ instead of zero.

Comment: @JoeM You can verify that the two statements are the same (for the $+$ case),
$$\cos(\pi \frac n2) + i \sin(\pi \frac n2) = i^n \qquad \forall n\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: I think we both commented at the same time, please check my comment. Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\cos( \pi \frac n2) = 0$ if $n$ is odd, everything is fine as-is...

Comment: Yes, I can see your solution is correct, what im trying to say is that I can't see how $e^{\pm i \pi \frac n2} = \cos ( \pm \pi \frac n2 ) + i \sin (\pm \pi \frac n2) = \cos(\pi \frac n2) \pm i \sin (\pi \frac n2)=\pm isin (\pi \frac n2)$ like is stated on the red squares of my question, again $isin (\pi \frac n2) = \pm(i(-1)^{n-1/2})$ when n is even and $0$ when its pair

Comment: Again, if the identities in the red squares are correct, then by substituing say n=2 at both sides of the equation, should yield the same result. So again, taking the left side of the equation inside the left red square as an example, if n=2 $cos(2*\pi/2) + j sin(2*\pi/2)=-1$ this should be exactly the same if whe take the right side of the equation inside the red square, again for n=2 $j sin(2*\pi/2)=0$, which is not the same as the $-1$ on the left side of the equation, so my question remains, is the solution wrong or what is going on?

Comment: You missed a bit. $\cos(\pi \frac n2)$ need not (and is not for $n$ even) be $0$. It says that (for $n=2$)
$$e^{i\pi} = -1 = \cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi)$$
Wich is correct.

Comment: So you agree that the numerical substitution I did in my previous comment is correct and therefore the solution to the problem I posted is incorrect. Again, im not doubting the identities you posted, what im interested in is finding out how exactly $e^{\pm i \pi \frac n2} = \pm i \sin(\pi \frac n2)$ as the solution to the problem suggests.

Comment: @JoeM Oh, wow I just noticed that equals sign. Yes, we are both correct and the solution incorrectly claims $\cos (\pi \frac n2) = 0$.

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for, thankyou!